# how to get checked and unchecked check box values in an array using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, checkbox

how to get checked and unchecked check box values in an array using javascript/jquery.

I have a list of check boxes.
    Below is the sample code.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chkCountry" value="1" checked="checked" />India    
<input type="checkbox" class="chkCountry" value="4" checked="checked" />China     
<input type="checkbox" class="chkCountry" value="2"/>Pakistan    
<input type="checkbox" class="chkCountry" value="3"/>Japan
```

Here i want to get the checked values in a array unchecked values in another array.

And if again i want to unchecked the checked values(here India and China), i want to get the    values(1,4) in another array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map) to convert a jQuery object set to an array like

```
var $checks = $('.chkCountry');

var checked = $checks.filter(':checked').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
var unchecked = $checks.not(':checked').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

- [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map)
- [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get)
- [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector)
- [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter)
- [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not)

Comment: if there are already some unchecked check boxes are available, So its getting all the unchecked checkboxes value with current unchecked checkbox value, But Here I want only one unchecked checkbox value which is currently unchecked.

Comment: @kiranstack so your script is in a change event handler

Comment: Yes, its in onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

To get checked :

```
arrchecked = $('.chkCountry').map(function() {
    if(this.checked)
     return this.value;
}).get();
arrunchecked = $('.chkCountry').map(function() {
    if(!this.checked)
     return this.value;
}).get();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pa7uh15p/)**

Comment: use `var` with `arrchecked` and `arrunchecked `

Comment: this will return arrays with `true` and `false` values... I don't think that is what OP is after

Comment: Updated the answer with fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var checked=[], unchecked=[];

$('.chkCountry').change(function() {
     if(this.checked){
          checked.push(this.value);
          unchecked.splice(this.value, 1);
     }else{
          unchecked.push(this.value);
          checked.splice(this.value, 1);
     }
}).change();
```

---

I stated a `.splice()` method to remove element if you need to update the array with uncheck.

Comment: if there are already some unchecked check boxes are available, So its getting all the unchecked checkboxes value with current unchecked checkbox value, But Here I want only one unchecked checkbox value which is currently unchecked.

Comment: @kiranstack you can place a trigger at the closing like in the code:`}).change();`.

Comment: still its not able to get the current uncheched checkbox value..instead its getting all the unchecked checkbox values